# What is the correct syntax for updating the state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

What is the proper way of updating the state using react-hook?

```
const [items, setItems]= useState([]];
const onChangeHandlers= (values)=> {
setItems({setItems:values})
}
const values = ['item1','item2','item3'];`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have the function of changing the value

```
 1:  import React, { useState } from 'react';
 2:
 3:  function Example() {
 4:    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
 5:
 6:    return (
 7:      <div>
 8:        <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
 9:        <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
10:         Click me
11:        </button>
12:      </div>
13:    );
14:  }
```

Your example

```
   const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

   const onChangeHandlers= (values)=> {
   setItems(values)}};
```

Comment: yes, I understood it but when updating the initial values from empty array with the array values... what is the way?

Comment: For example,,                                                     import React, { useState } from 'react';
const values = [
    {id:1,name:"One"},
    {id:2,name:"Two"},
    {id:3,name:"Three"},
]
const FilterWithReactPicky = ({values}) => {
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
const onChangeHandlers = (values) => {
 setItems({items:values})
}
return (
    <div>
        <h1>Filter With React Picky</h1>
        <button onClick = {onChangeHandlers}>Click</button>
    </div>

)
}
export default FilterWithReactPicky;

Comment: Check the correct answer by clicking on the check mark next to my message.

Answer (score 1):

A few important things to keep in mind while updating state via useState updater hook is

1. The state updater doens't merge the state instead replaces the existing state with the new one
2. State updater isn't aware of what name you give to state, in your case you call it `items`.

The correct way here to just pass in the new value as you would do while calling a normal function

```
const [items, setItems]= useState([]];
const onChangeHandlers= (values)=> {
   setItems(values)
}
const values = ['item1','item2','item3'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

const onChangeHandlers = values => {
    setItems(prevState => ([
        ...items,
        values
    ]);
};

const values = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
```